# By Passing Wildcard filename to get all the files unioned in Azure dataflow dataset?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a new dataflow ,at the source i have given Wildcard file name as
input/*.csv

Does this do the union of all csv files under input folder and out put it ?

Because When I do an aggregate on bothe source1 and source 2 ,source 1 has higher row count than source 2.
Does that meant ,we can union like this without union transformation?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By Passing Wildcard filename to get all the files unioned in Azure dataflow dataset?

Yes, it provides output similar to union transformation irrespective of schema of files are similar or not. if any column is not present any of the file it will return null values for that column in other files similar to union transformation.

[image]

> Does that mean, we can union like this without union transformation?

As Union transformation can union only 2 datasets as per blew image you can use wildcards to union all files with file name you are passing to match.

[image]

Comment: In union also we can add as many as files ,there will be a plus (+) symbol beside the Union with

Comment: It will make it as union of union with that dataset at  time you can pass only two incoming streams to union transformation